# Consulta mal estructurada

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Realice esta consulta para generar una gráfica pero me manda un error que no termino de solucionar, si me pueden echar una mano de favor. Esta consula es fabricada con condiciones pero en alguna condicion haca algo mal y no agrega algun paretesis, en lo que he esta do probando la funcion "convert" no tiene parentesis de cierre pero ya probe en varios lugares y me marca el mismo error, lo que si ubico es cual "AS" es el que marca el error: "**AS y**" es donde asigno el alias y.
consulta:

```
SELECT CONVERT
(
    NUMERIC ( 10, 1 ),
    (
        (
            COUNT ( * ) * 100.00 / (
            SELECT COUNT
                ( * ) 
            FROM
                control_prenatal cp
                LEFT JOIN direccion d ON d.id = cp.fk_direccion_id
                LEFT JOIN cat_codigo_postal catcp ON catcp.id = d.fk_codigo_postal_id
                INNER JOIN cat_unidad u ON cp.fk_unidad_id= u.id 
                AND (
                    (
                        DATEDIFF(
                            week,
                            FORMAT ( CAST ( cp.fecha_ultima_menstruacion AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ),
                            FORMAT ( CAST ( GETDATE( ) AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) 
                        ) 
                    ) >= 0 
                    AND (
                        DATEDIFF(
                            week,
                            FORMAT ( CAST ( cp.fecha_ultima_menstruacion AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ),
                            FORMAT ( CAST ( GETDATE( ) AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) 
                        ) 
                    ) <= 40 
                ) 
                AND ( cp.fecha_resolucion IS NULL ) 
            ) 
        ) 
    ) AS y,
    catcp.zona AS name 
FROM
    control_prenatal cp
    LEFT JOIN direccion d ON d.id = cp.fk_direccion_id
    LEFT JOIN cat_codigo_postal catcp ON catcp.id = d.fk_codigo_postal_id
    INNER JOIN cat_unidad u ON cp.fk_unidad_id= u.id 
    AND (
        (
            DATEDIFF(
                week,
                FORMAT ( CAST ( cp.fecha_ultima_menstruacion AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ),
                FORMAT ( CAST ( GETDATE( ) AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) 
            ) 
        ) >= 0 
        AND (
            DATEDIFF(
                week,
                FORMAT ( CAST ( cp.fecha_ultima_menstruacion AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ),
                FORMAT ( CAST ( GETDATE( ) AS DATE ), 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) 
            ) 
        ) <= 40 
    ) 
    AND (
        cp.fecha_resolucion IS NULL 
    WHERE
        zona != '' 
GROUP BY
catcp.zona
```

Error:

> Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'AS'.
> [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'AS'. (156)

Comment: Tras una ojeada rápida: no uses funciones como parámetros al llamar otras funciones. Trata usando una variable `@mydate = getdate()` y usa esa variable en todos los lugares donde haces datediff contra getdate

Comment: ¿`fecha_ultima_menstruacion` no es tipo DATE? te ahorrarías mucho. Te falta cerrar justo antes del `AS`.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias por la recomendación, la tendré en cuenta

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas pero el ya encontre el probleme y esa al momento de armar la consulta con los IF

Comment: Puedes poner tu solución como respuesta, así otros con el mismo error sabrán qué deben buscar. Puedes marcarla como aceptada más adelante, incluso